# Construct a circular loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, cyclic

I want to loop a list over a cycle. 
ex: I have three elements in the array L = [1,2,3]
I want to get the output as

L[0],L[1]

L[1],L[2]

L[2],L[0]

Is there a easy way get the slightly different output

L[0],L[1]

L[1],L[2]

L[0],L[2]

Comment: Reverse duped only because the other post has better answers. If there is a dispute, please ping me here or in the [Python](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) chatroom

Answer (score 3):

Using modulus operator

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> for x in range(10):
        print a[x % len(a)]
```

Using `itertools.cycle`

```
>>> iterator = cycle(a)
>>> for _ in range(10):
        print next(iterator)
```

As for your output, you could just do this.

```
>>> for x in range(10):
        print '{0}, {1}'.format(a[x % len(a)], a[(x+1) % len(a)])

>>> 1, 2
>>> 2, 3
>>> 3, 1
... etc etc
```

Comment: The `itertools.cycle` is pretty interesting! Although from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle): "Note, this member of the toolkit may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on the length of the iterable)."

Answer (score 1):

You can just use increasing index, and use modulo (remainder of division)

```
myList = [1,2,3]
for i in xrange(len(myList)):
    myTuple = (myList[i],myList[(i+1)%len(myList)])
    print myTuple
```

will produce:

```
(1,2)
(2,3)
(3,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
L = [1,2,3]
length = len(L)
for i in xrange(length):
        print L[i % length], L[(i+1) % length]
```

Output

```
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

This way, you can do something like `xrange(10)` and still have it cycle:

```
1 2
2 3
3 1
1 2
2 3
3 1
1 2
2 3
3 1
1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [0,1,2,3]
for i in xrange(0, len(l)):
    print l[i], l[(i+1) % len(l)]


0 1
1 2
2 3
3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a recipe in the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) that you can use:

```
import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)
```

Call this with `itertools.cycle(L)` and you're good to go:

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
for pair in pairwise(itertools.cycle(L)):
    print pair
# (1, 2)
# (2, 3)
# (3, 1)
# (1, 2)
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean **combinations**? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

```
from itertools import combinations
comb = []
for c in combinations([1, 2, 3], 2):
    print comb.append(c)
```

For sorting you can use then

```
sorted(comb, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```